# Notice: Undefined index: login_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\SIMS\header.php on line 9

Tags: php

**This is my header.php**

The only problem i am facing is that the  notice on the bottom of my screen but login is working properly as it should be.When I submit username and password it pass through another page.The notice shows error on `if($_SESSION['login_id']=="")`.

```
<?php 
        var_dump($_SESSION);
       if($_SESSION['login_id']=="")
        {
            ?>    
            | <a href="index.php?page=login">Login</a>  | 
            <?php   
        }   
        else
        {
            echo "<font color='green'> | Welcome ".$_SESSION['login_usr']." ".$_SESSION['login_id']."  | Logged in as ".$_SESSION['type']." | </font>";
            if($_SESSION['type']=="Admin")
            {
                ?> <a href="index.php?page=main_record_officer">
            <?php
                }
            if($_SESSION['type']=="Student")
            {            
                ?> <a href="index.php?page=main_student">
             <?php } 
             if($_SESSION['type']=="Teacher")
            {
                ?><a href="index.php?page=main_teacher">
            <?php }
             if($_SESSION['type']=="Accountant")
            {
                ?><a href="index.php?page=main_accountant">
             <?php } ?>
            My Page</a> | <a href="logoff.php">Logoff</a> | <?php
         }              
        ?>
        <a href="index.php?page=help">Help</a> |
```

**This is my login.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']))
    {
        $user=$_POST['usrname'];
        $pass=$_POST['password'];

        $sql="select * from record_officer where admin_name='$user' and admin_password='$pass'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($count==1)
        {
                $_SESSION['login_usr']=$row['admin_name'];
                $_SESSION['login_id']=$row['admin_id'];
                $_SESSION['type']="Admin";
                print "<script>window.location='index.php?page=main_record_officer';</script>";
        }

else if($pass==""||$user=="")
        {
            echo "<center><font color='red'>Required fields are empty !!! </font></center><br><br>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<center><font color='red'>Invalid user name and password !!! </font></center><br><br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Did you start the session in all pages using sessions? If not; **do**.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to start your session by including `session_start()` at the top of your pages, at least, the ones that need the session functionality. That said, replace your test: `if($_SESSION['login_id']=="")` with this:

```
if( isset($_SESSION['login_id']) && ($_SESSION['login_id']=="") )
```

Comment: I have already started include session_start() on top of pages and replace with this  line but the problem in same ...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using empty (http://php.net/empty) as it first checks if a variable is defined at all and then if it has content.

So this:

```
if($_SESSION['login_id']==""){
}
```

should better be:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['login_id'])){
}
```

And as mentioned you need to make sure your session is active, for example like this, at the beginning of the document:

```
// PHP >= 5.4
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

// ..or else:
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
```

Beware that you will encounter the "undefined.." error whenever you try to access a variable that is not yet set.

So you need to check your code and add checks wherever necessary.

For example:

```
$user=$_POST['usrname'];
$pass=$_POST['password'];
```

Should be:

```
$user = empty($_POST['usrname']) ? "" : $_POST["usrname"];
$pass = empty($_POST['password']) ? "" : $_POST["password"];
```

This way the variables $user and $pass will be "" in case the variables were not sent.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: usrname in C:\xampp\htdocs\SIMS2\login.php on line 32   Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\SIMS2\login.php on line 33..... Now I am getting this notice on login.php....